# Install Command Line Interface in my machine

Tags: command-line-interface, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using databricks and I am trying to install the CLI into my machine to make a connection to a storage. I am able to pip install it but I cannot get the token to authenticate.

I think that my issue comes from not running my version in the correct python location or script.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Python 3.7, if you are using a different version of Python use the appropriate version

```
c:\> pip --version
```

If you get a path like this

```
C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip
```

Then databricks.exe is available under (replace site-packages\pip with scripts)

```
C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\scripts
```

Add this entry into your Environment variable Path folder.

Verify the installation using the following command.

```
c:\> databricks --version
```